Which reference frame is point cloud in?
I have to generate a point cloud using a RGBD image. I am using the following function from open3d. Which frame will be the resulting points in, camera frame or the world frame?
pcd_tmp = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_rgbd_image(
            rgbd,
            o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic(
                cam.image_width,
                cam.image_height,
                cam.fx,
                cam.fy,
                cam.cx,
                cam.cy,
            ),
            extrinsic=W2C,
            project_valid_depth_only=True,
        )

I want to get the point cloud in the world reference frame, is this the correct approach?

I have mainly used tensor api, so adding an answer for that.
pcd_frame = o3d.t.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_rgbd_image(
                    rgbd_image=rgbd_frame,
                    intrinsics=intrinsics,
                    extrinsics=extrinsics,
                    depth_scale=depth_scale,
                    depth_max=depth_max,
                    stride=1,
                    with_normals=False,
                )

However, to check if this is correctly done, its best to add world coordinate system and camera marker to view if everything maps correctly.
coordinate_frame = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_coordinate_frame(size=1)
cameraLine = o3d.geometry.LineSet.create_camera_visualization(
                    intrinsic=pinhole_intrinsic,
                    extrinsic=extrinsics,
                    scale=0.25,  # Use 0.25 meter as side length of lineset of camera lines
                )
open3d.visualization.draw_geometries([coordinate_frame, cameraLine, pcd_frame.to_legacy()], mesh_show_back_face=True)



Above pic shows how 5 cameras are located in the world. P.S. Focus of the answer is more on debugging tips.
